why does connect() return Uncategorized but not WouldBlock error in Rust socket2 crate
I use socket2 crate.
I set the socket in nonblocking mode, and call the connect().
I expect that it returns 'WouldBlock' error but it returns 'Uncategorized': Os { code: 115, kind: Uncategorized, message: "Operation now in progress" }. Why?
--- EDIT ---
I know the reason thanks to @Steffen Ullrich's comment. I thought InProcess is the same with WouldBlock. I am wrong. In fact EWOULDBLOCK is the same with EAGAIN. I got mixed up.
Ok, now my question changes:
I find that I have to handle the error for Unix and Windows in different way:
Unix (have to bring libc crate too):
if err.raw_os_error() != Some(libc::EINPROGRESS)

Windows:
if err.kind() != io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock

I use socket2 crate to avoid handling different OSes. But now it seem that I have to handle Unix and Windows?

Why do you expect WoudBlock? I could not find a part of the documentation that indicates that's what connect would return.

"Operation now in progress" (EINPROGRESS) is exactly what connect is supposed to return according to the documentation - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html

Please write your question as one cohesive one, not one with a lot of edit headers, that's discouraged because it makes your question harder to read for future visitors

"I use socket2 crate to avoid handling different OSes" well don't use it for that reason, it "provides as direct as possible access to the system’s functionality for sockets", that means such differences will not be abstracted at all.

@cafce25 Thanks for you reply. My original requirement it that, I am learning and trying to build a async-runtime, and I have finished the executor, and now I am working on Tcp Stream. The TcpStream in std-lib does not support nonblocking connect(). So I need a crate which abstracts socket-functions for different OSes. I test socket2 and now it seems not fit. Do you have any suggestion?

This is not the platform for recommendations, try [softwarerecs.se]

@cafce25 Ok, thanks.
